# How to remove all the links in the page using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am dynamically creating the links like

```
         var mydivs = document.getElementById("attach");
                            var bTag = document.createElement('a');                               
                            bTag.setAttribute('docid', "doc");
                            bTag.innerHTML = "doc";
                            mydivs.appendChild(bTag);
```

Then a link is creating dynamically. Then on button click i want to remove this link.
How can i remove this link on button click. I will be have more than one link in the page.
Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Where is jquery being used here?

Comment: Do you want to remove all the links? or just one?

Comment: I want to remove all the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use jQuery than you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('<a id="doc">doc</a>').appendTo('#attach');

  $('#my_remove_button').click(function(){
    $('#attach').find('a').remove();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this on click of the button :

```
element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

A tad bit easier solution will be if you use jquery instead

Answer (score 0):

Because you mention jquery, try this:

```
$("a[docid='doc']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

for (var i = aTags.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) { 
  if (aTags[i].hasAttribute('docid')) { 
    aTags[i].remove() 
  } 
}
```